# Single noun/phrase to denote transfer across levels of formality of language

Tags: synonyms, terminology, formality, register

Question: What is the name of the quality denoting the formality/colloquialism of and/or amount of jargon in language?

Context: I am writing a review for a paper in which authors developed a model that, taking informal descriptions as input, outputs formal names of the entities described.

Examples:

> He **said** he **was feeling tired** and then... --> Mr. X **reportedly complained of fatigue** before the accident.

> Doc, I really **struggle to breathe** --> Patient was admitted with
> **mild dyspnea**.

> I've been **having fever on an off** for the past few days --> **Has been experiencing intermittent fever**.

Is there a single term that captures the notion that language might have different level of formalism and/or level of field-specific terminology?

What I am currently considering writing: "[the model presented] performs entity linking across the language register and ...". I might even have to say "sociolinguistic language register" as register is an often-abused word in computer science, and I would rather keep it simple.

Does anyone happen to have an insight on this?

Comment: *Register* or *tone* apply here. What's unclear is whether the conversions add or subtract from the originals for sitting higher than needed.

Comment: Yeah, though they do it by picking one particular context (medical in this case) and slanting the vectors toward medical terminology, which is very consistent and precise. This is not the case in general, but the medical system generates so much data that I can see how this is a real advance.

Comment: If you were waterboarded and struggled to breathe, is that mild dyspnea? Complaining of fatigue does not need *reportedly* complained of fatigue.

Comment: @YosefBaskin thanks for your input. Clearly this is from a scientific publication assessing medical data, and waterboarding is quite uncommon in hospitals. *Reportedly* is a standard CYA word in medical records, pointing out the fact that the medical professional has not heard the patient's complaint himself. That makes a big difference in court.

Comment: In  [Language at the Boundaries: Philosophy, Literature, and the Poetics of Culture
By Peter Carravetta](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vdEZEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT119&lpg=PT119&dq=%22switch+register%22+rephrase&source=bl&ots=GZH48jOQMd&sig=ACfU3U041a9f7M4u2Wj_TWmfYbQ1mMGOjg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiL44S7t9_2AhVOQkEAHXnOA6AQ6AF6BAgaEAM#v=onepage&q=%22switch%20register%22%20rephrase&f=false) the author uses the prosaic 'Let me switch register momentarily and rephrase this preface.' Perhaps that's the best available. // The wry 'What's that in English?' works for highfalutin speech.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how your example should work:

> "[the model presented] performs entity linking across language **registers** and ..."

You would use **registers** in plural, since there are multiple *registers* and in this usage *register* is a count noun. You would also omit the article, since you are not specifying definite registers but describing how, as a matter of praxis, the model links examples across registers.

Other examples support the use of the plural form **registers** when discussing multiple registers, all registers, or moving across registers:

> ... one cannot generally come up with a feature dividing all **registers** into classes, with regard to this feature. (Salvatore Attardo, *[Linguistic Theories of Humor](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Linguistic_Theories_of_Humor/FEWC4_3MrO0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=linguistic%20registers&pg=PA238&printsec=frontcover)*, p. 238)

> I have observed also that **registers** are historically changing systems that are shaped by processes linking groups to each other in social space. In some cases the social domain of persons acquainted with the register is tightly delimited by institutional processes; other **registers** have a more amorphous social distribution. (Asif Agha, "Registers of Language" in *[A Companion to Linguistic Anthropology](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Companion_to_Linguistic_Anthropology/qMXdopSc7BIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=linguistic%20registers&pg=PA43&printsec=frontcover)*, p. 43)

> "But then there are other issues such as variability **across language registers** (e.g. according to level of formality), across genres and across varieties within a language. (Andrew Cohen, *[Learning Pragmatics from Native and Nonnative English Teachers](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Learning_Pragmatics_from_Native_and_Nonn/NsJ2DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22across%20language%20registers%22&pg=PT225&printsec=frontcover)*)

Comment: People use 'change gear' almost as often as 'change gears', if one can believe Google ngrams. Results for 'switch register' and 'switch registers' are fascinating.